# why is the error of self not defined occuring?

Tags: python

I am new to python and was making a quiz game using classes and objects but I ran into an error. Why in the last self.opt2 is not defined ?

I made a class templet that has a basic structure of question and answer then I def a function that would take and print question and answer to user and ask for input, if input matches the correct option ( here correct_opt ) , score is increased by 1

Here is the code
At last in que.lay() the error is occuring i.e self not defiend

```
print('Welcome to quiz game !!\n')
score = 0

class templet:

    def lay(self, correct_opt):

        print(self.que)
        print('a)', self.opt1)
        print('b)', self.opt2)
        print('c)', self.opt3)
        print('d)', self.opt4)

        ans = input('\nInput your answer: ')

        if ans == 'a':
            correct_opt = self.opt1
        elif ans == 'b':
            correct_opt = self.opt2
        elif ans == 'c':
            correct_opt = self.opt3
        elif ans == 'd':
            correct_opt = self.opt4
        else:
            print('\n Enter a valid value')

        if correct_opt ==  ans:
            print('Yay! you answered it correct')
            global score
            score += 1
        else:
            print('ooh !! you answered it incorrect')




que1 = templet()
que1.que = 'What does CPU stand for ?\n'
que1.opt1 = 'Central Power Unit'
que1.opt2 = 'Central Processing Unit'
que1.opt3 = 'Centralized Power Unit'
que1.opt4 = 'Centralized Processing Unit'

que2 = templet()
que2.que = 'What does GPU stand for'
que2.opt1 = 'Graphic Processing Unit'
que2.opt2 = 'Graphical Processing Unit'
que2.opt3 = 'Graphic Power Unit'
que2.opt4 = 'Graphical Power Unit'

que1.lay(self.opt2) # here
```

Comment: self is a local variable defined in the class. So, it should be used only inside the class. Instead use - `que1.lay(que1.opt2)`

Comment: You should be defining an `__init__` method to initialize the object so that it's ready for `lay` to be called as soon as `templet` returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is only defined in methods of a class. `self` is the reference to the class's instance object. Outside the method of a class, that instance object is stored in your `que1` variable. So, instead of

```py
que1.lay(self.opt2)
```

You need to put

```py
que1.lay(que1.opt2)
```